# Vue.js: How to prevent the user from entering characters other than letters and numbers

Tags: vue.js

I'm using vuetify components in my current project and now I am facing a problem:
how to prevent the user from entering characters other than letters and numbers?
I do not mean form validating I'd prefer not to alow to eter restricted symbols at all.
Should I create a directive or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put something like this as the onKeyPress event handler:

```
(event) => {
    if (!event.key.match(/[0-9a-zA-Z]/g)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

This will prevent key-presses outside the alphanumeric range from being entered. However, note that this is not foolproof (e.g. it will still allow you to copy-paste symbols into the field), so you might still want some sort of validation.